# How to configure Mailgun to be used with Sign in with Apple and Apple's relay service?

Tags: ios, mailgun, apple-sign-in, sign-in-with-apple

I have verified my domain as mentioned in the Apple Docs but I am still unable to send emails to apple relay addresses.

I have also added the sender email id from the Mailgun logs (postmaster@mail.mydomain.com) to the verified addresses.

But no luck.

SendGrid (https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/account-and-settings/configuring-sign-in-with-apple/) gives you one email address to be added to Apple Dashboard but I don't see a similar solution for MailGun.

If anyone has faced a similar scenario, please share how you overcame the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure your mailgun subdomain is verified. If your server is at `example.com` and your mailgun sending domain is `sender.example.com` you need to add the file you download from https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/services/configure to your host on `https://sender.example.com/.well-known/apple-developer-domain-association.txt` after this verification is successful you will see a green tick and mailgun emails to `*@privaterelay.appleid.com` which are registered against your developer account should be delivered.